# Inserting external parameter in map function with ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this function:

```
this.get('model').map(function(item){
            if(item.get('isSelected')){
                item.set('selectedClass', 'conversation-history');
            }
        });
```

What I would like to do :

```
this.get('model').map(function(item){
            if(item.get('id') == this.get('selectedConvId')){
                item.set('selectedClass', 'conversation-history');
            }
        });
```

This tells me this.get is not a function, and I understand why, I am not in the same scope. But how can I introduce an external parameter in the map function? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use variable `var self = this;` or `var selectedConvId = this.get('selectedConvId');`

for example

```
var self = this;
this.get('model').map(function(item){
  if(item.get('id') == self.get('selectedConvId')){
     item.set('selectedClass', 'conversation-history');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I advise you to use Ember.set or Ember.get. It works with Ember objects and plain javascript objects as well.